# jQuery - how to loop through array when clicking a link?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to change the `src` of an image when clicking on individual links (I only have 3).

So if I click on link #1, the `src` changes, if I click on link #2 it changes to something else, kind of like a basic image slider.

Here is a simplified example:http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/164/

the jquery I tried:

```
var images = [
    "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/",
    "http://linenwoods.com/images/kitten.png",
    "http://linenwoods.com/images/third.png"
],
    links = $("ol.list-inline > li > a"),
    img = $("figure > img");

links.each(function(){
    links.click(function(){
        img.prop("src", images[links.index()]);
        console.log($(this).index()); // only gives back 0 instead of 0,1,2 like
                                      // I expected ...
    });
});
```

How can I do something like this using jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The anchors are inside LI elements and have no siblings, as such their index is always zero.

```
var images = [
    "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/",
    "http://linenwoods.com/images/kitten.png",
    "http://linenwoods.com/images/third.png"
],
    links = $("ol.list-inline > li > a"),
    img = $("figure > img");


    links.on('click', function(){
        img.prop("src", images[$(this).closest('li').index()]);
    });
});
```

get the index() of the parent LI instead

Comment: Ah, that makes sense .. thank you for the fast response! will accept in 9 minutes.

Comment: I forgot to ask: can I add `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()` easily with your code to add a fade effect when the img changes?